# Overview of how to use the xml feed returned from an API in a static web page

Tags: jquery, xml, api

I need someone to give me a bird eye overview of how to use the information retrieved from an API  call. I believe I need to do a GET request using this string: (it is available in JSON and XML)

```
https://partner-int-api.groupon.com/deals.xml?country_code=IE&tsToken=IE_AFF_0_200012_212556_0&division_id=dublin&offset=0&limit=20
```

Can someone please tell me where to place the Get request and how to set it out? I.e. is it in the head of a web page ? Does it need to be inside jQuery script? I have no idea about this.

I have found many tutorials but they all start with some basic assumed knowledge - I'm missing some critical understanding here...

I understand HTML and CSS, I just want to pull the XML data in, I can format it ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS are just the view. In order to do a GET request, you need to use JavaScript. It's pretty easy if you use jQuery. You can read about making get requests in their [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

Once you have the data from the GET request, you can use other jQuery dom manipulation methods to do what you want with the data.